# is it possible to have users input tuple's for data output in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, user-input, qlineedit

I'm working on a small python project where I'm making a chemical calculator.
For starters started making a whole series of tuples consisting of all elements, since tuples can't be changed.
I want to be able to input singular and multiple elements, but in it's current shape it only seems to work with *multiple* inputs for some reason. I had to resort to `eval` here in combination with `input` in order for the input to be picked up as a tuple, although I heard `eval`is generally considered bad practice since it allows all types of input from the user, even harmfull input

```
#snippet of element list data in order of name, electrons and atomic weight, hydrogen and oxygen are use in examples.
Hydrogen = ("Hydrogen" , 1 , 1.008)
Helium = ("Helium" , 2 , 4.003)
Lithium = ("Lithium", 2 , 6.941)
Beryllium = ("Berylium" , 4 , 9.0122)
Boron = ("Boron" , 5 , 10.811)

mollmass = eval(input( "Enter atoms in the molecule: ")) #input needs a comma (,) or plus sign(+) to work

#outputs every element entered, can't multiply values, recurring elements need to be enterd multiple times
for elements in mollmass:
   print(f"atomic weight of the element", elements[0] , "is", elements[2]) 

elemental_sum  = 0

#calculates total weight of the molecule
for atomic_weight in mollmass:
    elemental_sum = elemental_sum + atomic_weight[2]
print("The mollmass of this molecule is", elemental_sum)
```

the output of this is

```
atomic weight of the element Hydrogen is 1.008
atomic weight of the element Oxygen is 15.999
The mollmass of this molecule is 17.007
```

however when I enter only one element I get:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

It get's worse once I start adding in some basic UI elements, since I'm working with QlineEdit I use a `self.line.text`for my input area, however having `input` there just downright crashes my program(windows error prompt) and only having `eval` results in `TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object` however this is an issue for a later date currently since I first want to figure out how to get the program to work properly *without* UI.
anyone here knows how to solve this or has a pointer for me into the right direction?

considering this is my first "real" project all help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: The problem is that if there is only one element then the first for loop is looping on the list that the element is. Ex if only Boron is selected the for loop, loops on ("Boron" , 5 , 10.811) which means it should actually print: "atomic weight of the element B is r" before the error. Solve this with an if statement making sure there is more than one element, and if there isn't then treat it differently.

Answer (score 0):

- If the user types `2, 3`, the `eval('2, 3')` resolves to `(2, 3)`.
- If the user types `5`, the `eval('5')` resolves to `5`.

The difference is that the `(2, 3)` is a *tuple* of integers and the `5` is just a single integer – *not a `tuple`*. You loop expects `mollmass` to be some sort of iterable, but when it's a single `int` value, it raises a `TypeError`.

Instead, you can make `mollmass` always resolve to an iterable and get rid of `eval` in the process:

```py
raw_mollmass = input("Enter atoms in the molecule: ")
mollmass = [int(x) for x in raw_mollmass.split(",")]
```

To check some output, I ran this in the `python` repl (console):

```py
# Testing to see if this works
def get_mollmass_input():
    raw_mollmass = input("Enter atoms in the molecule: ")
    mollmass = [int(x) for x in raw_mollmass.split(",")]
    return mollmass

>>> get_mollmass_input()
Enter atoms in the molecule: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

>>> get_mollmass_input()
Enter atoms in the molecule: 3
[3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and code reference, I'm going to try this out as soon as I get the chance to properly do so